# Inserting Symfony NestedSet data via MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, nested-sets

On a Symfony exploration project, I have a model using doctrine NestedSet behaviour. Since the data is prepared in a flat file, I wrote a [conversion utility](http://www.prasadgupte.com/blog/converting-csvexcel-data-to-doctrine-yaml-fixtures/) to generate corresponding YAML. It turns out that processing NestedSet YML of around 100 records (max_depth=4) consumes over 40MB of PHP memory, which is not available to me.

Is there a work-around to this problem?

I'm thinking of 2 possible solutions.

1. Write an equivalent PHP script to populate objects & save them
2. Insert data via SQL statements, the challenge being to compute the left & right nodes

What do Symfonians suggest?

Comment: Pre-order travel algo explained: http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/

Comment: How is hierarchy represented in your flat file?

Comment: It has the foll fields: level, id, name, parent_id. So if fruit is a child of food, then the CSV data has 2 lines: 1=>[0, f1, Food, ] 2=>[1, f2, Fruit, f1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 2 was better.

I wrote a simple macro in Excel to compute the lgt and rgt values required for the pre-order tree. Logic as mentioned here: http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/
The same Excel utility would convert values to a SQL query that could be dumped via file.

Going through the fixtures/object route exceeded the allowed memory limit.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you insert the data in several times, one time per level starting at level 0, for instance.